# Индексация ссылки

Tags: php, ссылки, html

Здравствуйте, возник вопрос:

```
<!--dle_leech_begin--><a href="http://www.konkyrent.ru/engine/go.php?url=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5zcHJhdm1yYWtvdm8ucnU%3D" target="_blank">коды городов и стран, телефонные коды республики Башкортостан, порядок набора номера, а также телефонные номера Кугарчинского района</a><!--dle_leech_end-->
```

Что это за код? Эта ссылка ведет на страницу моего сайта, но почему здесь просто не прописан адрес моего сайта, а ссылка сначала ведет на страницу `go.php?www.konkyrent.ru` - это ссылающийся сайт. Будет ли индексироваться такая ссылка? Пожалуйста, будьте снисходительны, я изучаю html и php всего пару месяцев. По ссылке нажимала, открывается страница моего сайта.

Comment: @Регина, не забудьте принять верный ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это такая защита от индексирования - ссылка ведет на тот же сайт, но после перехода следует редирект на ваш сайт. Но поисковики-то видят ссылку на первый сайт.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все, что требовалось узнать! Я тут задавала вопрос, может ли это быть редиректом, мне сказали что это бред))).